# Jmeter TCP sampler used for what

Tags: tcp, jmeter

From http://abh1sh3k.blogspot.com/2013/11/simple-tcp-server-and-jmeter-as-client.html, I practiced and it ran well.

I don't understand, what the test (jmeter tcp sampler) is used for? My company usually uses a web application and a process application.
Who can show me any example?

Comment: google "http vs. tcp" and you will find out: https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=http%20vs%20tcp

Comment: Thanks Kiril S, i learn network badly, i read the link but not understand. Can u show me a example.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) which describes how communication is stratified over the internet, you will see that TCP/IP communications are part of the lower level *Network* and *Transport* layers (layers 3 and 4).  It is far more typical for JMeter tests to build around HTTP/S calls in the *Application* layer (which is layer 7).  However, JMeter extends the ability to create tests around lower-level communications using the [TCP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler).

There are several niche use cases for the TCP Sampler in creating JMeter load tests.  A few examples would be:

- Testing Internet of Things ([IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things)) devices
- Evaluating resilience of custom protocols
- Specialized applications which use non-standard protocols
- Compatibility testing across different network protocols

These are just a few such cases where testing at the TCP/IP level would be appropriate.  There is an article about [using the JMeter TCP Sampler](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2023/07/tcp-ip-testing-using-the-jmeter-tcp-sampler/) which walks through setup and configuration including examples and screenshots.